# Vue js : v-bind properties in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

quick question.

Trying to figure out (if its even possible) how can I say template length by binding properties into one object and then using v-bind to bind it

problem is
I'm using v-for, so I've got deconstructed objects

```
<tb-header v-for="(field, index) in tableFields"
                               :id="`header${+parseInt(index)+1}`"
                               v-bind="binds.styleProperties.header"
                               :field="field"
                               :col-num="index+1"
                               :style="field.thStyle"
                               :class="field.thClass"
                               :key="index">
                    </tb-header>
```

I can't figure out how to create a "bind" that's shorter (like...
`:field="field"` is dependent on the v-for deconstruction)

any ideas?

Comment: what does `binds` represent?

Comment: the binds are exactly what I want to use for all the properties i have to bind with the v-for

bind includes all template syntax, it saved template space

its a computed property
``
return {
                    styleProperties: {row, header},
                    tableClasses: ['tb-table', {'equal-width': this.config['equalWidth'] && !this.config.horizontal}],
                    tableContainerClasses: ['tb-table-container', {'busy': this.loading}, {'horizontal': this.config.horizontal}],
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, but if you want to create a bind that is shorter, probably you can do something like:

```
<tb-header v-for="({ thStyle, thClass, ...field }, index) in tableFields"
   :id="`header${+parseInt(index)+1}`"
   v-bind="binds.styleProperties.header"
   :field="field"
   :col-num="index+1"
   :style="thStyle"
   :class="thClass"
   :key="index">
</tb-header>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: nah man, I mean, I wanna bind the properties deconstructed from the v-for props.

So that i won't have to write the :field="field" and I can just put that in an object....to make the template thinner